# When I should use a store in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, redux

I have some questions about the store in ReactJS/Flux implementation.

Basically, I have all my API request which use store. But sometimes, I think store is an overkill features.

A simple example : 
I just want display a list of the five last user who have registered on the home of my dashboard. I never want to refresh this list until the user refresh the browser. Should I use a store just for that ?! Or maybe I can create a "global" store for my home page where I include all this little things like this (static display of data requested by the API).

I have another question about store, how much a medium-size application have store ? Because mine have already a lot of store (20-30).

You create one store by page ?! By models ?! By components ?!

Thanks for you response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: many Reducers, one Store.

You tagged this with Redux so I'm going to answer based on the assumption that you're either using Redux or want to use as your Flux implementation.

Regarding the number of Stores, from the Redux docs:

> It’s important to note that you’ll only have a single store in a Redux application. When you want to split your data handling logic, you’ll use reducer composition instead of many stores.

So it might be that you want to create a home Reducer to handle all the API responses for your homepage and save those to your single Store.

Comment: Your right, I use redux and reducer, Not store. My mistake. Thank you response. The scalability of the application is the problem and I think I will take your direction.

Answer (score 1):

In your simple example, probably you don't need a store, but I would still use one, as it makes your application scalable. You never know when you would be asked to add new features to it.

About your other question, it totally depends although 20-30 stores sound a bit excessive.

Personally, I use redux and I just have one store with multiple reducers which I combine using redux's combineReducers.

Comment: Like say @jolyonruss, I use reducer not store. It's a language abuse from me. How many reducer you have ?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? You must be using reducers and then creating a store in redux using createStore, no? Now, how many reducers I have totally depends on how complex my app is.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming a few things, but here is my attempt:

A store might be overkill in this case since there is no updating happening after the user refreshes the page. Seems like a static object to me. If you don't have a store already and want to keep going without one I would suggest (assuming you are using flux) to create your dispatcher events within the component that needs this list. The dispatcher will listen for events from your actions. I am guessing your actions make the back-end call to get the last 5 users so the action would then emit an event with the 5 users you are wanting. When the dispatcher receives the event you can set the list of 5 users within your component.

The use case for a store that I have found is when you have "living" objects that change with user interaction on your page. With a store it may be easy to live update your list of 5 users every so often based on an interval and it also serves a way of abstracting out the dispatcher logic from your component into a nice and neat store.

Comment: I think a lot like you but for scalability, I will use a "homepage" reducer and made all my API call from here. Thanks for you response.